# Python how to align Python dataframe output to centre

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to align Python dataframe output to center of console or output file. I have tried below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os   
cols = ('Employee Name','Employee AGE')
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Pawni/Desktop/test.csv",names = cols)
print(df.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns))
```

But it is giving error :
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'center'

So, it seems Center is not a attribute of dataframe. What other options available to print dataframe output to center of console.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `shutil` module, and `split` method

```
import shutil
import pandas as pd

data = {'test': [1,2,3], 'data': [4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert DataFrame to string
df_string = df.to_string()
df_split = df_string.split('\n')

columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(df_split[i].center(columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works entirely, but you might can use the `to_string()` method on the dataframe. `.center()` only works on a string.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'test': [1,2,3], 'data': [4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the DataFrame to a string
df_string = df.to_string()

# print the centered string
print(df_string.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns))
```

Comment: I have tried this but getting error: OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid